# Issue with Zapier Code - Simple if else statement

Tags: zapier

I have looked over this countless times and yet I get the error "You must return a single object or array of objects.

```
if (inputData.score === '0') {
  output = 'Passed';
} else {
  output = 'Failed';
}

return output;
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

In your code, you're returning a string, not a javascript object (`{}`) or array of objects (`[{}, {}]`).

change your code to the following:

```js
if (inputData.score === '0') {
  output = 'Passed';
} else {
  output = 'Failed';
}

return {result: output};
```